# Deprecation warnings in Qiskit (circuit drawing)

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am just starting to get around Qiskit, I'm going at baby steps, so I tried to run the code below and I noticed three things:

1. I tried using `matplotlib_circuit_drawer()` instead of `circuit_drawer()`, but is return a DeprecationWarning and sugested using `circuit_drawer`. I assume this is due to the constant updates and the functions are going to change frequently;
2. In the `qc.measure(q, c)` I get a highlight in PyCharm saying *Unresolved attribute reference 'measure' for class 'QuantumCircuit'*, and I don't know what that really means;
3. I think this is also related to 1). When using `draw(qc)` I get the warning `DeprecationWarning: The current behavior for the default output will change in a future release. Instead of trying latex and falling back to mpl on failure it will just use "text" by default
   '"text" by default', DeprecationWarning)` and no image pops up. However when I use `print(qc)` the circuit pops up in text format;

How can I be up to date about the commands?

```
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.tools.visualization import circuit_drawer as draw

c = ClassicalRegister(2)
q = QuantumRegister(2)
qc=QuantumCircuit(q, c)

qc.measure(q, c)
draw(qc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qiskit Terra 0.7](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/releases/tag/0.7.0) changed visualization quite a bit. [This blog post](https://medium.com/qiskit/terra-0-7-better-visualization-compilation-memorization-895b05b7197f) from the Qiskit team might be helpful.

Here's your code, updated for Qiskit Terra 0.7.2:

```
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit

c = ClassicalRegister(2)
q = QuantumRegister(2)
qc=QuantumCircuit(q, c)

qc.measure(q, c)

# draws an ascii circuit
print(qc)

# Output:
#             ┌─┐
# q0_0: |0>───┤M├
#          ┌─┐└╥┘
# q0_1: |0>┤M├─╫─
#          └╥┘ ║
#  c0_0: 0 ═╬══╩═
#           ║
#  c0_1: 0 ═╩════

# draws a circuit with Matplotlib 
diagram = qc.draw(output="mpl")

# if you'd like to save to a file
diagram.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```

Here's the SVG that was generated (converted to PNG for StackExchange):
[image]

As for your second question... this sounds like something with your IDE's access to the library symbols. I don't have help for you there, except to say it's a fairly common problem. Good luck!

---

*Note: This advice applies to Qiskit 0.7.x. Qiskit is rapidly evolving and you should expect breaking changes on new versions. You can find the release notes [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst).*

---

**Troubles installing Matplotlib/visualizations?**

Per the [blog post](https://medium.com/qiskit/terra-0-7-better-visualization-compilation-memorization-895b05b7197f), you should be able to run:

`pip install qiskit[visualization]`

While it has worked for me in the past, it currently returns:

`qiskit 0.7.2 does not provide the extra 'visualization'`

As a workaround, you can install the packages this "extra" [references](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/stable/setup.py):

`pip install matplotlib nxpd ipywidgets pydot`

Also, in the off chance you are using MacOS with `virtualenv`, you may run into [this issue](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html). I had to use `venv` to get it to work.

Good luck!